# Undefined mixin when using Bourbon Neat

Tags: css, sprockets, bourbon, neat

I am using [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/) and [Neat](http://neat.bourbon.io/), and have the following code

```
@include direction-context(right-to-left) {
  div.actions { @include shift(3); @include shift(10); }
}
```

and am getting the following error:

```
Undefined mixin 'direction-context'.
```

I have double checked the relevant [docs](http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#direction-context), however I do not understand why this is not working. Note that I am successfully using other mixins in the framework.

Update

I have the following versions:

```
  neat (1.5.1)
  bourbon (>= 3.1)
  sass (~> 3.2.19)
```

Comment: Can you please locate your `neat.scss` file and look at the version number at the top? If you are on Rails, that should be in your Gemfile.lock. The `direction-context` was added recently and you might be using an outdated version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `direction-context` mixin was introduced in 1.7.0. You will need to update you Sass stack if you want to use it, since 1.7.1 works only with Sass 3.3 and above.

Alternatively, you can change direction in Neat 1.5.1 using  `@include row($direction: RTL);` on the parent element, then calling `@include reset-direction();` once you are done (at the bottom of the file, usually).